# Two dimensional array handling in awk

Tags: awk, syntax-error, gawk

I am trying a simple awk scripts for two-dimensional array which is given below:

```
BEGIN{
     b[1][1]=0
     split("5 4 3 2",b[1])
     print b[1][1]
}
```

This code snippet also mentioned in gnu gawk tutorial. But when I tried to run this I got syntax error for the indices of b. Can anyone tell what is the issue? In gnu tutorial they have shown the output.

Comment: Are you using GNU awk?

Comment: Note that true 2-d arrays like the above are only available in newer versions of gawk so even if you're using gawk it might not support that syntax.

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATED**

Normal `awk` uses `b[1,1]` syntax, but it is not a real 2D array. Rather a hash, having elements like `1 SUBSEP 1`. So if you use `for (i in b) print i` then you will have such indices. Default value for `SUBSEP` is 0x34, but can be redefined.

`split` is not working to define an array element. But you can move to a normal variable and fill up `b` with a for-loop. Let's try:

```
BEGIN{
     #b[1,1] is automatically created if referenced, even by a read.
     split("5 4 3 2",b[1]);
     print b[1,1];
}
```

Says: "awk: ./x.awk:5: fatal: split: second argument is not an array"

Next try:

```
BEGIN{
     split("5 4 3 2",a);
     b[1] = a;
     print b[1,1];
}
```

Nope. Error: "awk: ./x.awk:5: fatal: attempt to use array `a' in a scalar context"

What You can use to store the result of the split in an array and then copy it to the 2D like stuct:

```
BEGIN{
     split("5 4 3 2",a);
     for(i in a) b[1,i]=a[i];
     print b[1,1];
}
```

Be aware that `b` is not a real 2D array. Now it has 4 elements like these: `b[1 SUBSEP 1] == 5`, `b[1 SUBSEP 2] == 4` &c.

If You would like to dump the values of be, You can create two loops or just one, like:

```
for (i in b) print i" => "b[i];
```

Output:

```
11 => 5
12 => 4
13 => 3
14 => 2
```

If You want to see the separator, set it to something visible:

```
BEGIN{
     SUBSEP=":"
     split("5 4 3 2",a);
     for(i in a) b[1,i]=a[i];
     print b[1,1];
     print b[1 SUBSEP 1];
     for (i in a) print "a-"i" => "a[i];
     for (i in b) print "b-"i" => "b[i];
}
```

Output:

```
5
5
a-4 => 2
a-1 => 5
a-2 => 4
a-3 => 3
b-1:1 => 5
b-1:2 => 4
b-1:3 => 3
b-1:4 => 2
```

As You can see the hash elements are not printed in numerical order. I'm surprised that `b` printed that way. But You cannot trust this (see `a` elements).

**ADDED**

I checked with [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) 3.1.5 and the `b[1][1]` and `split("5 4 3 2",b[1])` notation does not work (as expected). I also tried [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) 4.1.0 and both are working! It seems in newer [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) the `b[1][1]=0` defines an array in `b[1]` so `split("5 4 3 2",b[1])` can work. But `b[1,1]=0` behaves differently. It behaves on the old way, so `b[1]` is not a real array (as no such element, rather `b[1 SUBSEP 1]`).

So try `awk --version` to check the version and use the old syntax as it seems your [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) is too old for the new syntax.

Comment: note that `for(i=1;i<=n;++i) b[1,i]=a[i]` can be written as `     `for(i in a) b[1,i]=a[i]`. For this example they are functionally equivalent but the latter is the right choice if there can be gaps in the indices of "a".